# JavaScript micro library for Ext JS style layouts?

Tags: javascript, layout

I've been developing with Ext JS for a while but a new project has me getting up to speed on the world of JS micro frameworks/libraries. Are there any JS layout libraries that provide an abstraction layer to do things that come close to Ext JS container style layouts [(hboxes, vboxes, anchor layouts, etc)](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html)?

I didn't seen anything on microjs.com but thought I'd ask here to double-check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research the CSS3 Flexible Box Model is everything I'm looking for.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

http://www.css3.info/introducing-the-flexible-box-layout-module/

http://www.the-haystack.com/2010/01/23/css3-flexbox-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

[MochaUI](http://mochaui.org/demo/) springs to mind (not a micro framework, but smaller than Ext).

Others that might interest you are [uki](http://ukijs.org/) and [Moolego UI](http://ui.moolego.org/demos/).

Comment: mocha, uki and moolego are interesting they're lighter weight alternatives to ext js but I'm looking for just a layout engine, no UI components.